# Are Ego and the Ego Gem related somehow?

Tags: marvel, infinity-stones

I know this is kind of a silly question, but ["Ego"](https://www.marvel.com/characters/ego) and ["Ego Gem"](https://www.marvel.com/items/ego-gem) are pretty similar.

Comment: Similar name, no obvious connection. Ego is an Eternal and the Ego Stone was part of Infinity, the being who existed before the universe began

Answer (score 5):

No, there is no evidence that the Ego Gem is related to Ego. The Ego Gem is the main consciousness of the Infinity Gems and when reunited with the other 6, it manifests as Nemesis a being capable of creating universes.

[image: Page explaining the Ego Gem] [image: Page showing Nemesis]
<sub>*Ultraforce/Avengers Vol. 1 Issue 1 pages - click images to enlarge.*</sub>

In fact as Ego, as far as I'm aware, is a being in a universe it wouldn't make sense for him to be connected to the Ego Gem. Also I'm pretty sure Ego and the Ego Gem have never come into contact in the comics. They have a similar name but that is where the connection ends.